# hide some button in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I want to ask how can I hide some button for different users? For example, an admin can access all buttons, but a regular member cannot access some buttons (e.g. add new user button).

Comment: How do you authenticate the user? Are you using ASP.NET membership providers?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Visible` property to `true` or `false` depending on your condition (check user),to hide or show.

```
  if(someConditionExpressionHere)
  {
     btnSave.Visible=true;
  }
  else
  {
    btnSave.Visible=false;
  }
```

Assuming `btnSave` is the Id of the button you want to hide/ show. You should udpdate the `someConditionExpressionHere` with a check to see whether the user is admin or normal user.

Comment: Also, assuming that the runat attribute is set to server too!

Comment: you can just write the code as `btnSave.Visible = someConditionExpressionHere`.  The entire if block is entirely redundant.